# Django/Python unittesting: How to Force Exception of Try/Except Block

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Is there any way to force the except block to execute so that I can verify the error messages/handling with unit testing? For example:

## views.py

```
def get_books(request):
    ...
    try:
        book = Books.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Unable to create new book!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_books'))

    # more try/except cases
```

So in this example, I could try to simulate an ORM failure or I can try to send in an invalid user for this case. But **is there a general way to throw exceptions (I'm open to using libraries)**? `Mock` for instance. Or is there some other method to use `unittest` to force exceptions? Obviously there are going to be many try/except blocks throughout the code, so I'm looking for any help.

Comment: Is it enforced with a `ForeignKey` for `Books` to have a unique `user` value?

Comment: @Duncan not a dupe - this is about covering the view with tests. Completely unrelated to what the other question is about. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I tried searching related. @alecxe, exactly. The problem is that there are going to be hundreds of `try/except` blocks and I can't inject `raises` to the view code every time I want to test. Well, maybe that could be done, but it won't be elegant. PS this question is there a general solution for unit testing; not only this specific example I provided.

Comment: It is clear that you need to use mocking, but, generally speaking, mocking Django's ORM is not trivial as far as I recall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `unittest.mock` to do it. You should patch `Books.objects` object by `patch.object` and use `side_effect` to raise exception. A complete test of your method exception behavior should be:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, ANY
from django.test.client import RequestFactory

class TestDjango(unittest.TestCase):    
    @patch("your_module.messages")
    @patch("your_module.HttpResponseRedirect")
    def test_get_books_exception(self,mock_redirect,mock_messages)
        r = RequestFactory().get('/I_dont_konw_how_to_build_your_request/')
        objs = Books.objects
        with patch.object(objs,"get_or_create", side_effect=Exception()):
              self.assertIs(get_books(r),mock_redirect.return_value)
              mock_messages.error.assert_called_with(r, ANY)
              mock_redirect.assert_called_with(reverse('my_books'))
```

I used `ANY` do remove the string dependency. I'm not sure what you want test in your code (complete behavior or just redirect...), anyway I wrote a complete example.

---

If your project is not a legacy work consider to rewrite your method (and the new django's ORM calls) in TDD style where you have for instance a `_get_books_proxy()` function that just call the django ORM methods:

```
def _get_books_proxy(request):
    return Books.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

and now patch `_get_books_proxy()` directly by `patch` decorator as:

```
@patch("your_module.messages")
@patch("your_module.HttpResponseRedirect")
@patch("your_module._get_books_proxy", side_effect=Exception())
def test_get_books_exception(self,mock_get_book, mock_redirect, mock_messages)
    r = RequestFactory().get('/I_dont_konw_how_to_build_your_request/')
    self.assertIs(get_books(r),mock_redirect.return_value)
    mock_messages.error.assert_called_with(r, ANY)
    mock_redirect.assert_called_with(reverse('my_books'))
```

Moreover `_get_books_proxy()` behavior can be tested by patching `Books` and passing a simple `Mock()`:

```
@patch("your_module.Books")
def test__get_books_proxy(self,mock_books):
     r = Mock()
     self.assertIs(mock_books.objects.get_or_create.return_value, your_module._get_books_proxy(r))
     mock_books.objects.get_or_create.assert_called_with(user=r.user)
```

Now you have a sentinel that can yield to you if your *critical point behavior* will be changed.

I apologize if you find some errors (I cannot test it)... but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: I was not able to get the ORM patch to work (not to say your method is wrong, I probably just need to play with it more), but the second proxy function method worked. If I understand the concept, I should write helper functions on difficult-to-test parts of the code, and then unit test using a patch? It works, but doesn't that open the code up to more entry points for failure/security issues? In any event thank you very much for your help!