# Python - Patch a function dynamically called

Tags: python, django, mocking, tdd

*I want to patch an assignment template_tag but that question is not Django specific.*

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
@patch('the_caller_path.my_function', _my_mock)
class MyTests(...):
```

And the "obvious" error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: <module 'the_caller_path' from '...'> does not have the attribute 'my_function'
```

The problem is that `the_caller` dynamically calls `my_function`.

---

As expected, using the path were the function is declared has no effect:

```
@patch('the_real_path.my_function', _my_mock)
class MyTests(...):
```

`my_function` is not patched.

---

How can I **globally** patch a function?

Comment: My guess is that `patch.object` is the way to handle these cases, but you should provide a minimal runnable example or I can do just some speculations. I've already filed an answer on similar topic at [Django/Python unittesting: How to Force Exception of Try/Except Block](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27818257/4101725) but I'm not sure if I can adapt it to your case.

Comment: BTW, is better if you file an example that fit exactly your real case otherwise we can fall in a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: can you also show how exactly is your caller calling 'my_function'?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've found a workaround for now.  This is not an XY problem; changing the code in the function directly gets these tests to pass. @user3012759, I'll look into it again when I have time - the caller is something in the Django template rendering code.

Comment: Also I tried with `patch.object` but that didn't work either.

Comment: you can try to go through the Django code and see what's the exact context for the call, this may help you with the correct namespace to patch... but still may not be quite obvious, depending how obfuscated the templating code is - and i expect it to be quite obfuscated